# Problem with dict/json payload in Flask tests - Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, flask

Using Flask RestX, I have an endpoint that sets the entire value of the request payload to a key in the Redis database. Using Swagger and Postman I can confirm that the endpoint works.

But when I try to test it I get an error.

#### `tray_info_api.py`

```py
def create_tray_info_api(api: Api, db: AsyncGetSetDatabase):
    tray_info_endpoint = api.namespace(
        'trayinfo', description='APIs to Send tray information to the Front End'
    )

    wild = fields.Wildcard(fields.String)

    well_meta = api.model('Well Metadata', {
        'label': fields.String,
        'type': fields.String,
        'value': wild
    })

    well = api.model('Well', {
        'metadata': fields.List(fields.Nested(well_meta)),
        'status': fields.String(enum=('ready', 'sampled'), required=True)
        # and some other fields with string/integer/datetime types
    })

    tray = api.model('Well Tray', {
        'rows_count': fields.Integer(required=True),
        'columns_count': fields.Integer(required=True),
        'wells': fields.List(fields.Nested(well), required=True)
    })

    @tray_info_endpoint.route('/')
    class TrayInfoEndpoint(Resource):

        @tray_info_endpoint.expect(tray, validate=False)
        def put(self):
            run(db.set('tray_info', request.data))
            return run(db.get('tray_info'))
```

#### `test_info_endpoint.py`

```py
def test_put_info(app):
    info = {
        "rows_count": 0,
        "columns_count": 0,
        "date_loaded": "2020-08-19T14:11:29.320Z",
        "date_processed": "2020-08-19T14:11:29.320Z",
        # ... and all the other fields; this data is copy/pasted from a working Postman request
    }
    res = app.test_client().put('/trayinfo/', json=info)   
    data = json.loads(res.data)
    assert data == info
```

The debugger stops in the test on the line starting with `res = app.test_client`, saying "TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable".

If I put a breakpoint inside the api's `put` method and go into the console, I see that `request.data` is the data I sent, with the `b'` prefix on the entire JSON:

```
>>> request.data
b'{"columns_count": 0, "date_loaded": "2020-08-19T14:11:29.320Z", "date_processed": "2020-08-19T14:11:29.320Z", "rows_count": 0}'
```

I know this indicates that it's bytes, which seems to point toward the answer, except if that's the problem, then shouldn't the app not actually work in Postman? I can step through the entire `put` method without errors, it seems like the error is coming frmo the line in the test itself, which is really weird.

I've also tried `res = app.test_client().put(url, data=info)`, which results in `request.data` as `b''` (an empty payload), so that's not right.

Answer (score 0):

decode your bytes to unicode before hand

```
import json

data1 = {
  "field":b"bytes"
}
json.dumps(data1) # ERROR!!!

data2 = {
  "field":b"bytes".decode("utf8")
}
json.dumps(data2) # ALL Good now its a string
```

If you dump your json ahead of time you can include a "default_encoder" to handle objects that cant be encoded normally

```
def encoder(obj):
    if isinstance(obj,bytes):
       return obj.decode("utf8")
    return obj

json.dumps(data1,default=encoder)
```

Comment: I'm unclear how I would use this in my exact situation. Note that I've updated my question to show that the entire JSON is bytes, or the stringified JSON is bytes, or...whatever it is, you can see in my question.

Comment: you need to change whatever field is bytes to be unicode ... since you only show 2 fields that are ints, It is hard to help you exactly for your situation...

Comment: Good point! I've added some datetime examples, which appear to actually be strings. And I just tried `"date_loaded": b"2020-08-19T14:11:29.320Z".decode('utf8')` with the same result. Note in my edit that inside of `put`, `request.data` is `b'{"columns_count": 0" #etc }'` so I think the problem isn't in constructing the dict.

Comment: those are strings not bytes... if i copy and paste that dict it will json encode no problem

Comment: What about the `request.data`? Anyway, instead of going back and forth on the definitions of what's what, would you be able to edit your answer so that it involves my code directly? I'm still not able to apply what you've said to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joran Beasley for pointing me in the right direction. I finally figured out how to apply his advice on json decoding, but it wasn't something that was anywhere in my original post.

You can see that the `create_tray_info_api` method takes a database (dependency injection). In the real app, this is created with a Redis database, but in tests I use a fixture to inject a simple mock database, whose `set` method was:

```py
async def set(self, key, value):
    self.db[key] = value
```

The `request.data`, as I noted, was a bytes object containing the json info, which my `put` method writes to the database. I guess Redis takes care of encoding/decoding itself in some way (or maybe the browser/swagger/postman does that) which is why it works in the real app.

The mock database, however, just writes and reads it as is. So I needed to decode the bytes when saving to the database. Which only works, of course, for bytes, so I have to make sure that integers, strings, etc, pass through normally:

```py
async def set(self, key, value):
    self.db[key] = value.decode('utf8') if isinstance(value, bytes) else value
```

Then in the test, `data` returns as a string, so we need to convert it back to json in order to assert its equality:

```py
assert info == json.loads(data)
```